# Can't import apply_transform from keras.preprocessing.image

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I have been having issues importing `apply_transform` from `keras.preprocessing.image`. As far as I know the name has not changed according to Keras documentation. Anyone has any idea what might be the issue. I can, from the same library, import `ImageDataGenerator` for instance.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apply_transform` [has been removed](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/08c873669f39b37743014db99fcd2d308f8ea5ea#diff-93850fa46a789f2e5905894ad0e7bee4L239) from `image` module and [has been refactored](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/f16eb5e1801af205f73de64a41af7e90143ac641/keras_preprocessing/image.py#L1095) as one of the methods of `ImageDataGenerator` class. Instead you can define an instance of `ImageDataGenerator` class and use it:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

img_gen = ImageDataGenerator()
img_gen.apply_transform(args)
```

or you can use [`apply_affine_transform()`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/f16eb5e1801af205f73de64a41af7e90143ac641/keras_preprocessing/image.py#L250) method from `keras.preprocessing.image` module if it satisfies your needs.

And I think you are right. The [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#apply_transform) is wrong about this:

> `keras.preprocessing.image.apply_transform(x, transform_parameters)`

whereas it should be:

> `apply_transform(x, transform_parameters)`