# How to import the module apply_transform or replace it by other?

Tags: python, matrix, keras, transform

I can't import apply_transform and transform_matrix_offset_center.
I try with `ImageDataGenerator` but I get issues too!

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import apply_transform, transform_matrix_offset_center
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'apply_transform'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this depends on which version of keras are you running. According to this [Github-issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10662), there was a small confusion regarding the documentation. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51311062/cant-import-apply-transform-from-keras-preprocessing-image) solves your issue for the newest versions when it comes to `apply_transform`. In my Keras version (2.1.5) `from keras.preprocessing.image import apply_transform` works, but in later versions as explained in the previously mentioned post `apply_transform` was moved to `ImageDataGenerator`.

As for `transform_matrix_offset_center`, based on the source code of [keras.preprocessing.image](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py) it is clear in `line 21` that this `from keras.preprocessing.image import transform_matrix_offset_center` should work. You can refer to the [releases-timeline](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases) to get an idea about the different changes in each version

Comment: glad I can help :)